safe if: treat only exit status 1 as false, other non-zero as error
In bash's if, all non-zero exit statuses are treated as false. But often (like e.g. in grep -q), 1 is the only status which really means false, others indicate errors.
I can think of the following alternatives to the plain if "${cmd[@]}"; then echo yes; else echo no; fi:
Simple case
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o errexit -o pipefail
cmd=(bash -c 'exit 10')

st=0; "${cmd[@]}" || st=$?
case $st in
    (0) echo yes;;
    (1) echo no;;
    (*) exit $st;;
esac

Check for 0 or 1
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o errexit -o pipefail
cmd=(bash -c 'exit 10')

st=0; "${cmd[@]}" || st=$?
[ $st -eq 0 -o $st -eq 1 ]
if [ $st -eq 0 ]; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi

Helper function to map status to output
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o errexit -o pipefail

# Put this somewhere for reuse:
map-status() {
    local st=0
    "$@" || st=$?
    case $st in
        (0) echo t;;
        (1) echo f;;
        (*) return $st;;
    esac
}

cmd=(bash -c 'exit 10')

st=$(map-status "${cmd[@]}") && if [ $st = t ]; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi

Questions

All of those have the problem that they require || after the check command, so errexit is not active in the check command. (Depending on the command, this can be fixed with a subshell with that option; but a subshell does not work when the command should set a variable for later use.) How can this be fixed?

Are there any other concise ways to write a careful if? Is one of them maybe even considered the idiomatic way?


Solutions should work with options errexit and pipefail enabled.

You seem to be labouring under the misconception that you can have only one command in the condition part of an if. You're free to use multiple commands: if whatever; ret=$?; [[ $ret = 0 ]]; then something; fi; if [[ $ret = 1 ]]; then something else; fi, etc. etc. Or even combine with a case: if whatever; ret=$?; [[ $ret = 0 ]]; then something; else case $ret in 1) something else;; 2) yet another thing;; esac; fi

@muru to be fair it's not well known that one can have multiple statements in the conditional part of if or while. For that reason I'd suggest you might like to turn your comment into an answer

@muru Thanks. I actually knew, but didn't think of using multiple commands for this. That's a valid answer. I'd still like a more concise and readable way, though.

"so errexit is not active in the check command. (Depending on the command, this can be fixed with a subshell with that option", well, no, it can't. ( set -e; false; echo hello ) || true runs the echo too. Probably best to avoid using errexit, at least that way you don't have to guess what you're going to get.

@rowboat Thanks, fixed.

@ikkachu Thank's for the correction. Not really a subshell, but you could use bash -e -c … there to make -e work.

In bash if is testing for an exit status, not a boolean, and an exit status has the values 0 for success or non-zero for failure. So the statement 'In bash's if, all non-zero exit statuses are treated as false.' is misleading at best as there is no "false" associated with an exit status and then the followon statement 'But often (like e.g. in grep -q), 1 is the only status which really means false, others indicate errors.' is also misleading at best since no value means "false", all non-zero values simply mean "failure". Thinking of an exit status as a boolean leads to bugs.

@EdMorton But a bash if has clearly a then and an else part, I just loosely called executing the else as "treating as false" etc. For grep -q, I obviously meant "not found" with false, and that's something you'd typically handle in one of the branches. Sorry, I don't see any take-away from your comment.

@EndlosSchleife, yes, I imagined you might have meant starting an independent shell process and that would indeed prevent the -e in there from seeing the conditional context outside. But a subshell is a very clearly defined concept, and starting an independent child shell is not it! A subshell is a copy of the shell environent, so it inherits e.g. all shell variables, exported or not. var=foo; (echo $var) prints "foo", but var=foo; sh -c 'echo $var' does not.

@EndlosSchleife yes, bash has if-else but it's not testing a boolean and the take-away should be what I said in my last sentence "Thinking of an exit status as a boolean leads to bugs.". The concept has a name, exit status, so just use that - no need to muddy the waters by talking about it as if it were a boolean which has completely opposite semantics (if 0 then foo pseudo-code does not execute foo if the test is for a boolean, but it does if it's testing an exit status).

You only need to test in any special way if the exit status of grep is non-zero, which I do here in the elif branch of the if statement.  The expansion ${status=$?} expands to the value of $? and sets the value of status to whatever $? is.  This makes status available to both the elif branch and the else branch, would you want to use it for something.
#!/bin/sh

unset -v status

if grep -q Hello file; then
        echo pattern matched
elif [ "${status=$?}" -eq 1 ]; then
        echo pattern did not match
else
        printf 'error (status %d)\n' "$status"
fi

Or, if you don't care to display or use the value returned from grep:
#!/bin/sh

if grep -q Hello file; then
        echo pattern matched
elif [ "$?" -eq 1 ]; then
        echo pattern did not match
else
        echo some kind of error
fi

The code above would work the same regardless of whether you ran it with bash and enabled the pipefail or the errexit setting, since the command is executed as part of the if statement.  In general, only use errexit sparingly, when you have a series of commands and don't want to put || exit behind each of them (then disable the setting again).  See also Greg Wooledge's Bash FAQ about this.
If this is the "idiomatic" way to do this, I don't know.  People usually don't make a difference between the non-zero exit statuses of grep.  However, this might be because the difference between grep erroring out and grep not matching a pattern in a file may not matter to most scripts.

I guess that's as concise as it gets. Accepted this answer. Thanks

I guess you could do something like this:
#!/bin/bash
careful() {
    "$@"
    local ret=$?
    if [ "$ret" -ge 2 ]; then
         printf >&2 "command '%s' returned error status %d, exiting...\n" "$*" "$ret"
         exit "$ret"
    fi
    return "$ret"
}

if careful grep -e '***' file; then
    echo match
else
    echo no match 
fi

where the function explicitly checks the return status of the given command before returning.
That would also work in other contexts like careful whatever || ...,
but it won't catch e.g. redirection errors that happen before the function is called, but then I think those just set $? to 1 anyway (in the shells I tried, incl. Bash and zsh).

Nice! I didn't know that I don't need || inside a function.

The approach I usually use in my scripts when I want to do something like this is:
safe_run() {
    case "$-" in
        *e*) set +e; _reset_e=1 ;;
        *) _reset_e='' ;;
    esac

    "$@"

    _safe_run_rc=$?

    [ -n "${_reset_e}" ] && set -e

    return 0
}

safe_run cmd

case "${_safe_run_rc}" in
    0) echo "SUCCESS" ;;
    1) echo "FAILURE" ;;
    *) echo "UNKNOWN" ;;
esac

This approach is POSIX compliant, meaning it works EVERYWHERE (even on all of the notoriously problematic busybox sh implementations), and it also does not care if the script it’s running in sets the errfail flag or not. The safe_run function wraps the command to be executed such that if set -o errfail is enabled, it will be disabled only long enough to run the wrapped command and save the return code and then re-enabled, while still preserving the output and return code.
I also personally prefer a case statement for this type of thing, since it’s more concise than an if statement and does not require saving the exit code or relying on semantics that many people do not know about (while it’s likely the case that many people do not know what $- does, I would argue that most people will be able to infer pretty easily from context what it is, while the same is not true of the handling of $? as applied to conditions in if statements).
All that said though, this is not something that comes up very often in my experience unless you’re dealing with either a script that wraps some other command to provide a more useful interface for it, or are invoking a function or command that you wrote yourself which uses the return code to communicate more than a simple pass/fail status.

you could use case $- in *e*) set +e; _reset_e=1 esac to avoid running an external program just for that. Also, should that be return "$_rc"?

Tested with Cygwin bash 5.2.21(1) and additional set -o errexit -o pipefail, this exits before the case for cmd status 1 or >1. According to the -x option, the last command is e.g. return 2.

@ilkkachu Yeah, that was a typo at the end of the function, and good point about the flag check.

@EndlosSchleife Yeah, that’s almost certainly a result of the typo that ilkkachu pointed out. I’ve updated the answer to fix that now (and make the flag check more concise).

Add local _reset_e _rc at the star of your function so they are function-local variables and so can't clobber any other variables of the same name.

@AustinHemmelgarn No, I already had @ikkachu's fix applied. Taking your current version plus set -o errexit -o pipefail as line 2 and replacing cmd with bash -c 'exit 2', I still don't reach echo "UNKNOWN".

@EndlosSchleife Ah, quite so. I should have just copied the code from one of the scripts where I’m actually using it instead of rewriting it from memory. I’ve updated it now to fix the actual issue.
